# react how to call state variable from another class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Search.js**

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedPictures: []
    }
  }

  static getSelectedPictures = () => {
      return this.state.selectedPictures;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default Search;
```

**Other.js**

```
import Search from './Search';

class Other extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        }
      }


     render() {
       console.log(Search.getSelectedPictures); --> Uncaught null
       return (
         <div>
           ...
        </div>
        );
     }
    }

export default Other;
```

How to call **Search.state.selectedPictures** inside **Other.js**?

I already try to use static method to return `this.state.selectedPictures` and call in **Other.js**, but cannot access.

Any way can import or transfer the var? Both js files are separate files

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Search.selectedPictures` a function? It doesn't appear in your code. I assume you don't mean `state.selectedPictures`?

Comment: @MattFletcher I want to access``Search.state.selectedPictures`` in Other.js

Comment: Ah you confused me by using the term "call", like it's a function.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Search` and `Other`? Is one a child component of the other? Are they siblings? Most likely you need to move the state up to a common parent that can then pass it down in props.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no they don't have relationship for now, separate files

Comment: Yeah. `Search` by itself is a class, not a constructed object. You can't just call methods or get properties from it before it's instantiated. And React's method of instantiation means you can't just do `new Search()`, so you'd probably need to have `<Other />` be a child of `<Search />`, or share a common parent like C-A says

Comment: @MattFletcher so do u mean ``class Other extend Search`` instead of ``Component`` ?

Comment: I am asking about their relationship in the DOM, not in the code structure. Please illustrate how `<Other>` and `<Search>` are used by other components.

Comment: @DonaldWu Nope. As in `Search`'s render function would contain `<Other selectedPictures={this.state.selectedPictures} />`, and then that property would be accessed within the `Other` component

Comment: @MattFletcher so I have to ``import Other from './Other'`` in Search.js? then use ``<Other selectedPictures={this.state.selectedPictures} />`` inside ?

Comment: @DonaldWu That is one option. But I think you're a bit confused about how React components work. They have to be used with the `<MyClass/>` syntax (correct me if I'm wrong); you can't just do `import X from Y` and then try and access properties with `X.something()`. You couldn't even do that with normal ES6. But basic `new X()` syntax would remove all reactiness from it.

Comment: You modified your comment so mine doesn't make as much sense, but pretty much. Or you have a parent component that contains the state, then renders both `<Search/>` and `<Other/>` with that state as their properties. Depends on what "Other" is, really.

Comment: in Other.js, ``constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             myPictures: this.props.selectedPictures
        }
      }``?

Comment: Mmm, you could do. But would there be any reason to move it into the state? I'd assume the component would re-render when the state in the parent changes, so not sure if there'd be any benefit

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't really possible in React for a couple of reasons. First of all, you're trying to call methods and access properties on a *class*, not on an *object*. You would, in normal (modern) JS, be required to instantiate the class with the `new` keyword. For example, `search = new Search(); search.getSelectedPictures()` - this, however, isn't really how React works, and because your classes are actually components, you have to use the `<Search/>` component syntax in your render function.

As for getting access to the state in `Search`, you'd need to pass that state *from* `Search` *to* `Other`.

One way would be to pass the state into the props directly, so in search.js:

```
render() {
  <Other selectedPictures={this.state.selectedPictures} />
}
```

Then in other.js:

```
render() {
  this.props.selectedPicture.forEach((pic) => <img src={pic} />);
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a more umbrella parent component, and keep the state in there. Then pass that state to both components simultaneously, if the ones you list are not meant to have a parent-child relationship.

There are also, albeit slightly more complex, ways of doing what you wish but with `Search` as a child of `Other`, but without knowing what those two components actually are, it's hard to really tell.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my React, so if anyone has anything to add or correct me on this answer, please feel free to edit, or let me know and I'll make amends.

Comment: @DonaldWu No problem. Did it answer the question for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use flux architecture . The simple implementation is

> alt flux

Just create an Action and  a Store . When you select images just put them in the Store using Action then get them as props using `<AltContainer />`